# Making window previews in qt using QSCreen::grabWindow() function

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qthread

I want to make a screen caster application that captures a window or a screen directly to QQuickImage. To do so I made this header which has a thread object which frequently updates screen shots when signal received (sorry file was written in a poor language)

```
class OtherThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QString oldWritingFile = "filename.png";
    bool loaded = true;
public:
    int winId = 0;
    OtherThread(QObject *parent = nullptr):QThread(parent){};
    ~OtherThread(){
        if(isRunning()){
            requestInterruption();
            wait();
        }
    };
    void setParams(int id){
        winId = id;
    }
    void knowLoaded(){
        loaded =true;
    }
signals:
    void fileCacheChanged(QString);
protected:
    void run() override{
        while (!isInterruptionRequested()) {
            if(winId != 0 && loaded){
                bool success;
                loaded = false;
                if(oldWritingFile == QString::number(winId)+".png"){
                    if(qApp->primaryScreen()->grabWindow(winId).save(QString::number(winId)+"file.png")){
                        oldWritingFile = QString::number(winId)+"file.png";
                        success = true;
                    }else{success=false;}
                }else{
                    if(qApp->primaryScreen()->grabWindow(winId).save(QString::number(winId)+".png")){
                        oldWritingFile = QString::number(winId)+".png";
                        success = true;
                    }else{success = false;}
                }
                emit fileCacheChanged(oldWritingFile);
            }
        }
    };
};

class Controller : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QString oldWritingFile;
public:
    Controller(QObject *parent = nullptr):QObject(parent) {}
    virtual ~Controller() {}
    void changeFile(QString message){
        oldWritingFile = message;
        emit newFile(message);
    };
public slots:
    void startThread(){
        OtherThread *thread =new OtherThread;
        connect(thread, &OtherThread::fileCacheChanged, this, &Controller::changeFile);
        connect(this, &Controller::stop, thread, &OtherThread::requestInterruption);
        connect(this, &Controller::changePrint, thread, &OtherThread::setParams);
        connect(this, &Controller::loaded, thread, &OtherThread::knowLoaded);
        thread->start();
    }
    QString getLoadedFile(){
        if(oldWritingFile != NULL){
            return "file:./"+oldWritingFile;
        }else{
            return "file:./index.png";
        }
    }
signals:
    void stop();
    void changePrint(int id);
    void newFile(QString);
    void loaded();
};
```

and with my qml image i did this

```
Image {
        id: image
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "images/kalaripayattu.svg"
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        cache:false
        Component.onCompleted: {
            justThread.newFile.connect(updateFunction)
        }
        function updateFunction(filename){
            source = "file:./"+filename;
            justThread.loaded()
        }
    }

    JustThread{
        signal stopThread
        id:justThread
        onStopThread: {
            stop()
        }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            startThread()
            changePrint(id)
        }
    }
    Component.onCompleted:{
        applicationWindow.closing.connect(justThread.stopThread)
    }
```

but it has a really horrible fps.
can anything be done to increase fps?
Is there any easy  way to do this?

Comment: I would use [image provider](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickimageprovider.html) instead. An even more effective way is to create custom item derived from QQuickItem that paints an image.

Comment: yeah but what should i do if i want to update my image frequently.

Comment: I see no problem to do that. It depends on which method you choose. You can send a signal in case of image provider or update it directly in case of QQuickltem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Image` is not really made for displaying frequently changing images. What you want is [`VideoOutput`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-videooutput.html).

Here's what I would do :

You need to create a QObject derived class instance and set it as the source of the VideoOutput : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-videooutput.html#source-prop
Your class needs to have a `Q_PROPERTY(QAbstractVideoSurface* videoSurface READ videoSurface WRITE setVideoSurface NOTIFY videoSurfaceChanged)`

In your `setVideoSurface` method, you need to call the start method of QAbstractVideoSurface with a correct format (your size and the pixelformat, pixelformat should be QVideoFrame::Format_ARGB32 for desktop I guess).

And then when you want to update the VideoOutput (via a QTimer for example), you call the present method of QAbstractVideoSurface with a QVideoFrame you constructed from the QPixmap you got in QScreen::grabWindow.

For that, you could convert the QPixmap to QImage with [`toImage`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html#toImage) and then convert it to QVideoFrame with the[`QVideoFrame::QVideoFrame(const QImage &image)` constructor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvideoframe.html#QVideoFrame-3).

Comment: very nice solution!

Comment: sorry for late respond. I was in a meeting. really thanks for your answer. I'll check that out tomorrow.

Comment: but it isn't working for single windows when trying  qApp->primaryScreen()->grabWindow(xwindowid).toImage()

Comment: Isn't working isn't a good diagnosis. What and how is not working? are you sure about the windowId? Is the pixmap returned by grabWindow valid? What about the image from toImage? Maybe it's is the conversion to QVideoFrame that fails. Figure that out.

Comment: sorry for late respond i think it's an error with `QVideoSurfaceFormat` here's what i did to set format. 1) converted pixmap to  image using `pixmap = grabScreen(winId).toImage()` made new format using `QVideoSurfaceFormat *format = new QSurfaceVideoFormat(pixmap.size(), QVideoFrame::pixelFormatFromImageFormat(pixmap.format()))` and started using `surface->start(*format)` then start methode returns 0 without showing any messages.

Comment: single window capturing works with firefox like applications but not with nautilus, terminal,and other gnome application i think these images has an usupported image format

Comment: sorry the error was with the format it self. ARGB32_Premultiplied format is not supported by QAbstractVideoSurface

Comment: is there any way to display and image with alpha